# No overload for 'Button32_Click' matches delegate 'system.eventhandler'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got an error in Button32
Can someone help me fix it?

```
protected void Button32_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs d)
        {
          System.Windows.Forms.Keys iCode = d.KeyCode;
        }
```

If I remove `System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs d` I get a new error so that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct C# class KeyEventArgs for ASP.NET!

You can have a JavaScript function which recieves the key Handler and invoke a C# Server Side code!

You can check the Client CallBack feature in ASP.NET, to call Server code from Client Code!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx

Hope it helps u...